# Guava : how to add other states to the Service interface?

Tags: java, guava, swingworker

I think about to use the [Service](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.2/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Service.html) guava interface as a [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html), because in a SwingWorker I always need a *start* and *end* state.

I should write something like that :

```
class WorkerSomething extends 
 javax.swing.SwingWorker<Void, com.google.common.util.concurrent.Service.State>
 implements com.google.common.util.concurrent.Service
```

This way, I can only use guava service state to carry intermediates results. But I need some other intermediates states to publish my GUI.

How can I do that ? Is this idea a good idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: What would be the benefit of implementing Guava Service? If in addition to that, Guava Service.State does not have enough intermediate values to carry the information you need, then don't use it because you can't extends an `enum`.

Comment: @Guillaume Polet Yes it's perhaps a bad idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would definitively say that if the existing `Service.State` values are not appropriate for your needs, then `Service` itself is not appropriate for your needs.

Comment: If we can only use the Service.State, how is it possible to use guava service ? Perhpas it's possible to add application states with ForwardingService ?